# Where to start? Log in to website on console

Tags: c#, html, .net, web

I am from game graphics programming. So I know only the basis of web programming.

My ultimate goal is making application that interacts with website.

But for now my goal is

1. Log in to google on console. ( I chose google since it is famous thus I may able to find more resources related to them)
2. Print all the email's titles I received from the logged in account.

I am using C#.net. Please recommend me another if any alternative language suits my goal better.

I ve written following code.

```
static StreamReader Access(string url)
    {

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        return new StreamReader(dataStream);
    }
```

Using streamreader, I can read the html of the webstie as text.I reasoned that if I could read html as text on console, by reading it, I can somehow do the next step.

My attempt to read html of "http://www.google.com" led me to absurd failure. As it returned me following unreadable wall of text.

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="ko"
><head><meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image"><title>Go
ogle</title><script>(function(){window.google={kEI:'Ni1VVIC5CIbNmwXEgIG4DA',kEXP
I:'4016824,4017578,4017981,4018674,4019181,4020346,4020562,4020921,4022495,40227
56,4022999,4023083,4023166,4023367,4023567,4023678,4023971,4023979,4024157,40242
73,4024691,8500272,8500325,8500393,8500700,8500724,10200083,10200716',authuser:0
,kSID:'Ni1VVIC5CIbNmwXEgIG4DA'};google.kHL='ko';})();(function(){google.lc=[];go
ogle.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttri
bute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.https=function(){retu
rn"https:"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){};google.time=functio
n(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,d,h,k){var c=new Image,f
=google.lc,e=google.li,g="",l=google.ls||"";c.onerror=c.onload=c.onabort=functio
n(){delete f[e]};f[e]=c;d||-1!=b.search("&ei=")||(g="&ei="+google.getEI(h));a=d|
|"/"+(k||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+g+l+"&zx="+google.time();/^http:/i
.test(a)&&google.https()?(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),delete f[e]):(
c.src=a,google.li=e+1)};google.y={};google.x=function(a,b){google.y[a.id]=[a,b];
```

I believe I am on the wrong track to achieve my goal. I need help to guide myself to correct direction.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: I am requesting a recommendation for a place to start to teach myself web based applications. I have demonstrated my attempt and expressed my failure doing so as I didn't understand what I was doing. Should this "first step" question be prevented? I have failed to find fitting place to develop further my interested area. I do not see reason for someone to say "no" to this "question, where do I need to start. This is what I am doing, is this what am I supposed to do"?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right place for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

C# should provide you with the tools you need, I've written applications in C# that interact with websites through the basic Web browser component as well as using the HTML Agility Pack.

To get you started I'd recommend you take a look at what functionality the HTML Agility Pack has to offer and see whether it will help you solve your problem. You can download it at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com